# Can Ubuntu be installed on any hardware?

Tags: dual-boot, windows

I have my new laptop :

- Lenovo ideapad 330 15AST
- Processor is AMD A6
- With Windows preinstalled

Questions :

1. Now I want to use Ubuntu and Windows also. I tried to dual boot my pc. While dual booting, my pc displays a message that, there is no os installed on selected USB drive. How can I solve it?
2. I contact to Lenovo adviser and they told me that, if you run Linux on this laptop, it can corrupt your pc or Windows too. Is this right?

Comment: You can install Ubuntu on your laptop with dual boot. The support is correct. If you do it a wrong way, you can ruin your Windows installation.

Comment: 1. Does your USB/CD is still plugged in your computer? 2. If you do it bad, you can remove/corrupt Windows, and using Linux let you able to corrupt your computer too, so yeah, you need to understand what you would do with it

Comment: How did you create flash drive, you want gpt & UEFI bootable flash drive if using Rufus, not MBR & UEFI/CSM which is BIOS boot. Only use Windows to shrink NTFS partition. And reboot, so it can run chkdsk & make sure fast start up is off. Shows installer with screen shots. Both BIOS purple accessibility screen & UEFI black grub menu screen
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI
Also shows Windows 10 screens or similar to Windows 8
https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-10-with-uefi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From ubuntu.com:

```
2 GHz dual core processor or better
4 GB system memory
25 GB of free hard drive space
Either a DVD drive or a USB port for the installer media
Internet access is helpful
```

It is possible to corrupt Windows if you don't install the dual-boot properly.  I would suggest wiping the drive & installing Ubuntu first, then Windows afterward (your laptop should have come with a Windows installation disk to restore your data, which you can use to install Windows on its own partition).  This way, you can set the disk partitions properly & use the GRUB bootloader to pick your OS on boot.

Comment: I would warn you to do it this way. In order to be safe, you should start with a full backup of Windows (to a separate drive), for example made with [Clonezilla](https://clonezilla.org). Then install Ubuntu alongside Windows according to some detailed description of the steps ...

Answer (score 1):

You have to download the iso image for Ubuntu and then make your pendrive bootable. Then try to install Ubuntu (while doing this you'll get an option to install alongside windows). To make a bootable pendrive you can use Rufus or Unetbootin.

Comment: If possible, please be more detailed in your answer.